# Send updated response to Clients from Stackoverflow

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

In Stackoverflow website if I answer a question and left for 3 hours,after that when I come back and see the question I asked am getting reponse alerts in red color without refreshing page.

How can I achieve this using  J2EE technologie or this is related to some kind of AJAX call.?

Is this possible if No of Clients more than one also, as we do using JMS ?

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: I feel it's ajax request send by your browser in specific intervals.

Comment: Have a look at websockets. The top bar/inbox/reputations are powered using webshockets.

Comment: Definitely websockets, based on something like [socket.io](http://socket.io)